# how to set title of each page or post for SEO

Tags: seo

I developed my theme. and I set header.php.

And in Header.php, I set like this.

```
<title>My Site Name</title>
```

This makes search-engine confuse. Every page and posts title in head tag are same with site-name.

Do you have tips to set the title and meta tag for SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly set the title tag in a theme you shouldn't put it in header.php manually. Your header.php should have `wp_head()` somewhere between `<head></head>`, then you can let WordPress set the title tag by [adding support for `title-tag` to your theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag#Adding_Theme_Support):

```
function wpse_304818_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_304818_theme_setup' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow steps to add support for title tag as mentioned in the answer by @Jacob Peattie

If still, you want additional option to add SEO specific title and meta description, you can use Yoast SEO WordPress plugin, which provides additional custom fields to add the page title and meta description.

Yoast SEO: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

[image]